# Comparing on Type Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to sort a list by comparing its type

```
type Dakar = [Piloto]
data Piloto = Carro Numero Nome Categoria
            | Mota Numero Nome Categoria
            | Camiao Numero Nome
type Numero = Int
type Nome = String
data Categoria = Competicao | Maratona

inserePil :: Piloto -> Dakar -> Dakar
inserePil p (h:t) = sortBy (compare `on` Nome) (h:p:t)
```

but it gives me error. Whats the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nome` isn't a predicate, it's the name of a type.  You could do

```
nome :: Piloto -> Nome
nome (Carro _ n _) = n
nome (Mota _ n _) = n
nome (Camiao _ n) = n
```

Then you can use `` sortBy (compare `on` nome) ``.  However, there's already a function for `on compare`, and it's `Data.Ord.comparing`, so you could instead write

```
inserePil p ds = sortBy (comparing nome) (p:ds)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i have another problem when testing //

>inserePil (Carro 25 "Emanuel" Competicao) dak //
No instance for (Show Piloto) arising from a use of 'print' //
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
//
dak its a list of the Type Dakar.

Comment: @spacecows The error you're seeing tells you exactly what's wrong "No instance for (Show Piloto)".  This means that the compiler doesn't know how to convert your type into a `String` in order to print it to the screen.  Try adding `deriving (Show)` to your `data` declaration, or write your own `Show` instance for `Piloto`.